# Create a custom color palette in R

Tags: r, colors

I know that `R` is loaded with some color palettes automatically, such as `palette`, `rainbow` , `heat.colors` and `gray`.  I'm also aware of `RColorBrewer`.  But, what if I want to use a custom color palette and assign colors by name?  Is that possible?

My company's color palette is as follows:

```
#1A73BA (R: 26 G: 115 B: 186) - this is a blue
#FFDB43 (R:255 G:219 B:67) - this is a yellow
#B54B05 (R:181 G:75 B:5) - this is an orange
```

My company's initials are AT.

I'd like to be able to call those colors via a name rather than by the HEX or RGB because I don't remember them.  Ideally, I could create a file that would load into R automatically that would initiate these colors.

```
ATBlue <- #1A73BA
ATYellow <- #FFDB43
ATOrange <- #B54B05
```

Then, I could call the colors:

```
plot(x,y, col = "ATBlue")
```

I could put the values into a dataframe, then call them like so:

```
ATColors <- data.frame(name = c("ATBlue", "ATYellow", "ATOrange"), color= c("#1A73BA", "#F7D364", "#B54B05"))

plot(x,y, col = ATColors[3,2])
```

But I would need to know the location in the dataframe in order to call it correctly.

Can I create an element that will automatically load when R launches that would allow me call a custom color name into a plot?

Comment: This question would be fantastic to update with a ggplot2-centric response. for example, how to - using your company colours - to create custom continuous colour scale going from ATYellow to ATOrange so that later one could call ggplot + colour_scale_ATcontinuous. If I ever figure it out, I'll write this answer myself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answers (or at least is one possible answer to) your comments and edits:

```
ATblue <- rgb(26/255, 115/255, 186/255, 1)
 ATyellow <- rgb(255/255, 219/255, 67/255, 1)
 ATorange <- rgb(181/255, 75/255, 5/255, 1)

 plot(1:10, col= c(ATblue, ATyellow, ATorange), pch=20)
```

The definition method with rgb allows you to set an alpha level , thus allowing transparency on graphic devices that support it (at a minimum: 'pdf', 'windows', 'quartz' and 'X11').

You can also name a 'palette-vector'

```
palvec <-  c(ATblue=ATblue, ATyellow=ATyellow, ATorange=ATorange)
```

That vector could be accessed with either numbers or names:

```
plot(1,1) # to set up plot window
abline(h=c(0.8,1,1.2), col= palvec[ c( 'ATblue', 'ATyellow', 'ATorange' ) ] , lwd=40)
```

---

In general I think you will find that if you use all lower case there will be good correspondence for the base and graphics packages (loaded by default so no renaming will be necessary) with that gif-list. So it's already part of R. Let's say you wanted to find the R color name of "LavenderBlush". The vector of assigned color names is returned from colors() but it's rather big, so you can whittle it down with:

```
grep("lavender", colors(), ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE)
#[1] "lavender"       "lavenderblush"  "lavenderblush1" "lavenderblush2" 
#     "lavenderblush3" "lavenderblush4"
```

And say you wanted to see whether the Hex code for that color were the same as the one on your unreadable gif table:

```
 ccodes <- as.hexmode( c(256^(2:0) %*% col2rgb("lavenderblush")) )
 ccodes
 #[1] "fff0f5"
```

Yep. And for your example just use "seagreen":

```
> ccodes <- as.hexmode( c(256^(2:0) %*% col2rgb("seagreen")) )
> ccodes
[1] "2e8b57
```

If you have a hex-code value you can append "#" to it with `paste0`:

```
 paste0("#", ccodes)
#[1] "#2e8b57"
 plot(1,1, col=paste0("#", ccodes) )
```

If you have a vector of such values, `paste0` is also vectorized:

```
 ccodes <- as.hexmode( c(256^(2:0) %*% col2rgb(colors()[20:25])) )
 paste0("#", ccodes)
#[1] "#ffe4c4" "#eed5b7" "#cdb79e" "#8b7d6b" "#000000" "#ffebcd"
```

Comment: I updated the question to be a bit more clear.  I was just using that gif as an example.  Ideally, I would take my company's colors and make a palette out of it, so it would be 10 colors or so, not 200 or whatever it was.  I tried what you suggested, then made the plot again.  `plot(x,y, col = "ccodes")`, which returns this: `Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid color name 'ccodes'`.  This works though: `plot(x,y, col = "#2e8b57")`.  is there not a way to have ccodes work in that example? Thanks

Comment: As would have plot(x,y, col = "seagreen").

Comment: `paste0("#", ccodes) -> ccodes` then you can use it in your plot call as long as you drop the quotes: `plot(x, y, col = ccodes)`

Comment: @Dwin I edited the question to remove any reference to the normal web colors.  I think that was causing some confusion.  Hopefully the edit will make it more clear about what I'm trying to accomplish.  Thanks

Comment: The `rgb` function could easily accommodate your revised question. I'll post some code

Comment: This is really useful. But is there a way to put this in an R package? I'd especially like to share this with colleagues.

Comment: It seems like it would be a fairly small bit of code to use as a package, but certainly would be possible. You would just need to define a couple of functions configured to your liking and document them. There a package.function lying around somewhere or use an IDE that has packaging facilities or the Skeletor package.

Answer (score 2):

I would put the colours in a named vector like this:

```
ATcols <- c(blue = "#1A73BA", yellow = "#FFDB43", orange = "#B54B05")
```

Then you can get, say, blue like this: `ATcols["blue"]`.

If you want to be a bit fancier, you could create a named vector and a function:

```
AT_color_data <- c(blue = "#1A73BA", yellow = "#FFDB43", orange = "#B54B05")
ATcolor <- function(color="blue") {
         if (is.numeric(color)) AT_color_data[color]
         else AT_color_data[tolower(color)]
}
```

This gives you a few options for getting your colours:

```
ATcolor(2:3)
#    yellow    orange 
# "#FFDB43" "#B54B05"

ATcolor("orange")
#    orange 
# "#B54B05" 

ATcolor(c("orange", "blue"))
#    orange      blue 
# "#B54B05" "#1A73BA"
```

Alternatively, you could make your function behave a bit more like `rainbow` when providing a numeric argument:

```
AT_color_data <- c(blue = "#1A73BA", yellow = "#FFDB43", orange = "#B54B05")
ATcolor <- function(color="blue") {
         if (is.numeric(color)) AT_color_data[1:color[1]]
         else AT_color_data[tolower(color)]
}
```

then, for example:

```
ATcolor(2)
#      blue    yellow 
# "#1A73BA" "#FFDB43"
```

Comment: can't you just use a named vector?  then you could skip a few `unlist` statements, and just use `ATcolor <- function(x) AT_color_data[x]` (I think)

Answer (score -2):

```
library("grDevices")
plot(1:20,pch=20,col=col)
col=colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))(20) 
M <- matrix(runif(100),10,10)
M[lower.tri(M)] <- NA
image(M,col = col,frame=F,xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
```

Comment: This is not a custom palette at all, which is what OP asked for.  Nor does it assign colors by name.  -1